# What's the best online tool that can track my entire portfolio including gains/losses?

Tags: investing, online-tools, dividends, portfolio

My broker does a great job of keeping my positions current but has really bad views/reports while other sites do a great job of tracking gains/loss and other reports but they don't keep track of dividends etc very well over time.  I want a simple tool that I can enter my positions, when I purchased them and for how much and it tracks dividends(which I reinvest) and any additional purchases I make an is able to give me complete reports on how well they are doing overall etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tool like [WikiInvest](http://www.wikinvest.com/) the advantage being it can pull data from most brokerages and you don't have to enter them manually.

I do not know how well it handles dividends though.

Answer (score 1):

[Mint.com](http://mint.com) does this quite well.

The graph views of your budgets, investments, debts, and other aspects of your financial life can be shown in gestalt, or on a per-account basis (at least, it does for me).

See the [investment](https://www.mint.com/how-it-works/invest) "how it works" page for more information.

> "Find out whether you're beating the market–or it's beating you. Compare your portfolio to market benchmarks, and instantly see your asset allocation across all your investment accounts: 401k, mutual funds, brokerage accounts, even IRAs."

Comment: Maybe add a few more details about exactly *how* Mint addresses the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Google Portfolio does the job:

https://www.google.com/finance/portfolio

You can add transaction data, view fundamentals and much more.